# How do I filter on composite keys?

Tags: python, couchdb

I need filter this view:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.doc_type == 'asd'){
        emit([doc.date, doc.string_key_0, doc.string_key_1], doc.list_field);
    };
}
```

I do:

```
key_filter_0 = ['START_TIME', 'STRING0', 'STRING1']
key_filter_1 = ['END_TIME', 'STRING0', 'STRING1']
VIEW[key_filter_0:key_filter_1]
```

but the view only filtered with `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`. It just ignored the `STRING0` / `STRING1` key filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as 'key filters' in CouchDB.

Every item you emit into your view will be sorted by its key, and you can then find all items between a given startkey and endkey. In your case, items are first sorted by date then string_key_0 then string_key_1.

It sounds like you were expecting to only see items between 'START_TIME' and 'END_TIME' where all items had 'STRING0' for the second item and 'STRING1' for the third item, but this is not how CouchDB views work. They are a one-dimensional list of items, sorted by the whole key.

Comment: Hi, a coworker give a solution, i change the key of view [doc.string_key_0, doc.string_key_1, doc.date] and filter then with [string_0, string_1, date_start/end]... if i need filter only by date i do start=['a', 'a', date_start], end=[{}, {}, date_end] this work :D 
Thank for reading and answer my question.

Comment: that range will include ['b', a', date_start] (among other values). Is that what you want? You are not able to filter on the individual items of startkey and endkey, you can only get all values between two keys.

Comment: Hi, dont work for date now... yes for the 2 first keys :P i will create more views and use the view i need depending the filter.